# Arranging and combining multiple plots and graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have 4 plots/schematics. They are either created with ArrayPlot[], ParametricPlot3D[] or Graphics[]. As I play with calculation resolutions their absolute sizes will change. I would like a neat way to arrange them inside a YouTube sized box (1920 x 1080) using relative positioning so that when/if they change size the final combination still looks more or less how I want.

To simplify the question let's say I have:

```
videoBox = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1920,1080}]}];
plot1 = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 3}]}];
plot2 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}];
plot3 = Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}];
plot4 = Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]}];
GraphicsRow[{videoBox, plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}]
```

[image]

Using relative positioning I would like to combine them to look something like:

[image]

Any suggestions?

**Update 1**

The answers and suggestions have certainly helped, but I still need more control over the positioning. For example here is the actual image I have created using the suggestions so far:

[image]

Close but no cigar. I would like to move the blue and red dots schematic up so that the bottom lines up with the bottom of the rectangular box plot.

Comment: `GraphicsGrid` comes to mind...

Comment: Yeah. I thought about that, but couldn't think how to get round problem of wanting the blue rectangle to take up two rows.

Comment: `GraphicsGrid[{
  {plot1, plot3, plot2},
  {SpanFromAbove, videoBox, plot4}}]` but I'd use `Inset` probably

Comment: That didn't seem to quite work. Oh but that's a good tip, I get how that works now, will have a play :)

Comment: GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot3, plot2},{SpanFromAbove,plot4,SpanFromLeft}}] gives me more or less what I want just not with it inside and filling up the videoBox

Comment: re: your Update 1: Try making the bottom scale of the plot a separate element and place it in its own row.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean, but that sounds like it could be quite complicated?

Comment: Unfortunately, Mathematica (for all its wonder) does not have a simple or direct way that I know of to do what you want to do.  I may have missed something (or a lot), but I'd love to have a way of specifying absolute size of each cell in a grid object of some kind (e.g., GraphicsGrid[], Grid[], ???) and then have the ability to put whatever I want into them specifying the absolute size of each element as well.  Having absolute control of alignment in each cell as well as spacing would help too.  This sounds like a simple idea, but it seems hard to do.  I'd love to see a solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
plot1 = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 4}]}];
plot2 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}];
plot3 = Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}];
plot4 = Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]}];

GraphicsGrid[{{plot1, plot3, plot2}, {SpanFromAbove, plot4, 
   SpanFromLeft}}, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, the caveats with this answer are: Changed the size of the blue rectangle and the frame is not the videoBox graphic given in the question.